# Where i can read more about UI tricks

Tags: website-design

I'm looking for book or maybe blog about UI tricks. What i mean when calling UI tricks?

Is for example when you have a black text and light background and in site area i do reverse trick like put light text on black background.

Another trick is for example we have a label inside div box and push it outside borders and this trick add some 3D effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://uxmovement.com/ read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To study such UI tricks you can refer below links because I studied same site and currently I refer it regularly. And you can also refer pinterest because it contains many dashboard for the UI-UX ideas so by following such discussion board you will get new tricks for the design.

www.dribble.com
www.uimovement.com
pinterest.com

Comment: the best one I use is behance.net

Comment: yes that's also one of the good website. I also refer it. I forget to mention here.

Comment: Do you have your portfolio over there?